# Meteor + Blaze, replacing one html tag to another

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I need to implement a feature that works like this:
1. User has `input` field
2. When he starts typing, I track if this text is overflown
3. (What I need to implement) If text is overflown, `input` changes to `textarea`, and back if text is reduced, and afterall share the text between `input` and `textarea`

So far I have the following code:

```
<div class="container">
    {{#if multiline}}
        <textarea class="size"></textarea>
    {{else}}
        <input type="text" class="size" />
    {{/if}}
</div>
```

The most obvious way I see to implement this feature is using `Session`, I have the following function:

```
multiline: function () {
    Session.get("multiline");
    if ($(".size > input").prop('scrollWidth') > $(".size >   input").width() ) {
    Session.set("multiline", true);
    } else {
    Session.set("multiline", false);
    }
}
```

So as you can see I calculate current sting's length to see if it's overflown. If I check `Session` variable in console, I can see that this calculation works the way I want, but `input` doesn't transform to `textarea` when `Session("multiple")` equals true.
Where am I wrong? Or may be there are other ways to implement what I need?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It was easy. I kept html and divided logic between `helpers` and `events`.
My new `multiline` helper looks like this:

```
multiline: function () {
    return Session.get("multiline");
  }
```

And I added an event to `Template.body.events` that looks like this:

```
"keyup .size": function (event, template) {
        if (event.target.scrollWidth > event.target.offsetWidth) {
            Session.set("multiline", true)
        }
    }
```

Worked like a charm.